# C# CSV import to Nest JSON

Tags: c#, json, csv

I'm using the following CS to upload a CSV file from a simple form and convert it into json and output it:

```
    class Article
    {
        public string slug;
        public string contentTypeId;
        public string contentTypeName;
        public string name;
        public string description;
        public string language;
        public string alreadyPublished;
        public string mainContent;
        public string refID;
        public string SEOpageTitle;
        public string SEOdescription;
        public string SEOKeywords;

        public static Article FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] values = csvLine.Split(';');
            
            Article article = new Article();

            article.slug = values[0];
            article.contentTypeId = values[1];
            article.contentTypeName = values[2];
            article.name = values[3];
            article.description = values[4];
            article.language = values[5];
            article.alreadyPublished = values[6];

            article.mainContent = values[7];
            article.refID = values[8];

            article.SEOpageTitle = values[16];
            article.SEOdescription = values[17];
            article.SEOKeywords = values[18];   

            return article;
                        
        }     
    }

    public partial class ArticleImporter : PortalModuleBase
    {
  
        protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strFileName;
            string strFilePath;
            string strFolder;
            strFolder = Server.MapPath("./files/");

            strFileName = csvUpload.PostedFile.FileName;
            strFileName = Path.GetFileName(strFileName);
            if(csvUpload.Value != "")
            {

                strFilePath = strFolder + strFileName;

                List<Article> values = File.ReadAllLines(strFolder + strFileName)
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(v => Article.FromCsv(v))
                    .ToList();
                    
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values);
                
            }
        }

    }
```

This seems to be working well, and results in the following JSON string:

```
[{
    "slug":"slug",
    "contentTypeId":"12345",
    "contentTypeName":"Article",
    "name":"Article Title",
    "description": "Description",
    "language":"en-US",
    "alreadyPublished":"FALSE",
    "mainContent":"Main Aritcle\\n\\n",
    "refID":"",
    "SEOpageTitle":"SEO Title",
    "SEOdescription":"SEO Description",
    "SEOKeywords":"test"
}]
```

The problem is that I need some of these values grouped and nested in traditional JSON fashion like so:

```
{
    "slug": "slug",
    "contentTypeId":"12345",
    "contentTypeName": "Article",
    "name": "Article Title",
    "description": "Description",
    "language": "en-US",
    "alreadyPublished": false,
    "details": {
        "mainContent": "Main Aritcle\\n\\n",
        "refID": ""
    },
    "seoSettings": {
        "pageTitle": "Title",
        "description": "Description",
        "keywords": [
            "csv",
            "importing"
        ]
    }
}
```

Can I break the details and SEO settings sections out with this approach to get the desired result?

Comment: Make `details` and `seoSettings` into nested objects on `Article` and populate them in your `FromCsv` method.

Comment: Where do you expect the different keywords to come from? Are they comma-separated in the CSV field?

Comment: This answer explains a better strategy to work with CSV https://stackoverflow.com/a/77233006/1704458. To make something like `"details": {
        "mainContent": "Main Aritcle\\n\\n",
        "refID": ""
    },` you need to have nested classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably want to create a class structure that models the JSON. For example, if I take your sample JSON and put it into an online tool like https://json2csharp.com/, I get this:

```
    public class Article
    {
        public string slug { get; set; }
        public string contentTypeId { get; set; }
        public string contentTypeName { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public bool alreadyPublished { get; set; }
        public Details details { get; set; }
        public SeoSettings seoSettings { get; set; }
    }

    public class Details
    {
        public string mainContent { get; set; }
        public string refID { get; set; }
    }

    public class SeoSettings
    {
        public string pageTitle { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<string> keywords { get; set; }
    }
```

Then you need to map your values:

```
        public static Article FromCsv(string csvLine)
        {
            string[] values = csvLine.Split(';');
            
            Article article = new Article
            {
                slug = values[0],
                // ...
                alreadyPublished = bool.Parse(values[6]),
                details = new Details
                {
                    mainContent = values[7],
                    refID = values[8]
                },
                seoSettings = new SeoSettings
                {
                    pageTitle = values[16],
                    description = values[17],
                    keywords = values[18].Split(",").ToList()
                }
            };
            return article;
        }
```

This code assumes the SEO keywords are comma-separated: you may have to tweak it based on your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically map your object(or model) from a CSV or XLS file, use CsvHelper, available at https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper.

Comment: Yes, this helps a lot than writing our own code or reinventing the wheel. Time saving too. Just explore this library via nuget and once you have your class model based object, serialize it to create the json.