# Dividing a csv file into multiple csv files in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, csv

I am trying to divide 1 csv into multiple csv files based upon what is in the first column.

example:

MainFile.csv

```
101, Jacobs, 123456
111, Joey, 78910
101, Billy, 654321
111, Robert, 45612
```

If the file has a 101 in the first column I am trying to create a new csv file with that as the name and only write data to that file that has 101 in the first column and continue all the way down the list.

Example:

101.csv

```
101, Jacobs, 123456
101, Billy, 654321
```

111.csv

```
111, Joey, 78910
111, Robert, 45612
```

I am currently getting either blanks or when I change things around I get all the data in each csv file any and all help is appriciated.

What I have so far:

```
reader = New StreamReader("R:\FilePath\MainFile.csv")
Dim stALL As String = reader.ReadToEnd
Dim LineToWrite As String
Dim LineOfMonitorID = File.ReadAllLine("R:\FilePath\MainFile.csv")
For x_DOF = 1 TO LineCount 'Counting all line in the MainFile
    Dim data = LineOfMonitorID(x_DOF)
    Dim splits = data.Split(","c)
    For y_DOF = 0 To 2DArray.GetUpperBound(1)
        2DArray(x_DOF, y_DOF) = splits(y_DOF)
        MonitorID = 2DArray(x_DOF, 0)
        LineToWrite = 2DArray(x_DOF, y_DOF)
    Next 'y_DOF
    If MonitorID = "101" Then
        MonitorIDTextFile = New StreamWritter("R:\PathToNewFile\101.scv", True)
        MonitorIDTextFile.WriteLine(LineToWrite)
    ElseIf MonitorID = "111" Then
        MonitorIDTextFile = New StreamWritter("R:\PathToNewFile\111.scv", True)
        MonitorIDTextFile.WriteLine(LineToWrite)
    End If
    MonitorIdTextFile.Close()
Next 'x_DOF
reader.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start small and just get the first part working:

```
Dim newFileFolder As String = "R:\PathToNewFile\"
Dim dataFile As String = "R:\FilePath\MainFile.csv"

Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile)
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
    Dim line As String = lines(i)
    Dim values() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Dim MonitorID As String = values(0)
    Dim newFileName = Path.Combine(newFileFolder, MonitorID & ".csv")
    IO.File.AppendAllText(newFileName, line & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

Here is how to make it clear out any existing data the first time it hits a new data file:

```
Dim newFileFolder As String = "R:\PathToNewFile\"
Dim dataFile As String = "R:\FilePath\MainFile.csv"

Dim SeenFile As New Dictionary(Of String, Boolean)

Dim lines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile)
For i As Integer = 0 To lines.Count - 1
    Dim line As String = lines(i)
    Dim values() As String = line.Split(","c)
    Dim MonitorID As String = values(0)
    Dim newFileName = Path.Combine(newFileFolder, MonitorID & ".csv")

    If Not SeenFile.ContainsKey(newFileName) Then
        SeenFile.Add(newFileName, True)
        ' Reset File Length to Zero for a possible already existing file:
        Using fs As New FileStream(newFileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
            fs.SetLength(0)
        End Using
    End If

    IO.File.AppendAllText(newFileName, line & Environment.NewLine)
Next
```

Comment: Your a genius THANK YOU!!! It worked but how did it work  what does   IO.File.AppendAllText(newFileName, line & Environment.NewLine) do?

Comment: From [File.AppendAllText()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=net-7.0#system-io-file-appendalltext(system-string-system-string)): "Opens a file, appends the specified string to the file, and then closes the file. If the file does not exist, this method creates a file, writes the specified string to the file, then closes the file." The `Environment.NewLine` part makes it go down to the next line after writing the string.

Comment: Be aware, though, that if you run this multiple times you're going to end up with the same data being appended to the already existing files. If you need the files to start fresh on every run, then you'd have to check whether you've seen a particular "MonitorID" before, and delete an existing file the first time you see it before appending new data. You could possibly use a [Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionarybase?view=net-7.0) to track those.

Comment: I am running into that issue now actually. How do you overwrite the existing file? I want to be able to overwrite it all every single time that it is ran. I have been using the ("FilePath.csv",True) in the past. But I have never used anything like this before.

Comment: See code at the bottom of the edit above.

Comment: Again I want to say thank you! I have been pulling my hair out trying to figue that out I was trying IO.File.WriteAllText And that just added one line. You have taught me so much and I can not thank you enough!

Answer (score 0):

When working with CSV, it is good to use good tools. For example, CSVHelper. One way to use it

```cs
// create a model for your file
public class Model
{
  ....
}

// create property mapper
public class Map : ClassMap<Model>
{
    public Map()
    {
        // map properties by name or index here
    } 
}

// use this generic method to load 
public static List<TModel>? LoadCsv<TMap, TModel>(string? path, bool hasHeader = true) where TMap : ClassMap<TModel>
{
    List<TModel>? modelList = null;

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path))
    {
        var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        {
            HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader,
            PrepareHeaderForMatch = args => args.Header.ToLower(), // make header all-lower so that any changes in headers will not change the mappings.
        };

        try
        {
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
            using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, config))
            {
                csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap<TMap>();
                modelList = csvReader.GetRecords<TModel>().ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
                // handle
        }
        return modelList;

}

// use LINQ to split the file 
var fileswith101 = modelList.Where(m => m.Col1 == "101");
var fileswithout101 = modelList.Where(m => m.Col1 != "101"); // just one option of many

// persist the list using same CSV Helper 
 . . . . .
```

This may be not the least-code method but I guarantee you that working with CSV tool like CSVHelper is way more reliable way for working with CSV than parsing it as string yourself.

**VB**

```vb
Public Class Model

    ' add properties
End Class

Public Class Map
    Inherits ClassMap(Of Model)

    Public Sub New()
         ' MAP properties
    End Sub
End Class

Public Shared Function LoadCsv(Of TMap As ClassMap(Of TModel), TModel)(ByVal path As String?, ByVal Optional hasHeader As Boolean = True) As List(Of TModel)?
    Dim modelList As List(Of TModel)? = Nothing

    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(path) Then
        Dim config = New CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) With {
            .HasHeaderRecord = hasHeader,
            .PrepareHeaderForMatch = Function(args) args.Header.ToLower()
        }

        Try

            Using streamReader = New StreamReader(path)

                Using csvReader = New CsvReader(streamReader, config)
                    csvReader.Context.RegisterClassMap(Of TMap)()
                    modelList = csvReader.GetRecords(Of TModel)().ToList()
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
             ' handle
        End Try

        Return modelList
    End If
End Function

Dim fileswith101 as List(Of Model) = modelList.Where(Function(m) m.Col1 = "101")
Dim fileswithout101 as List(Of Model) = modelList.Where(Function(m) m.Col1 <> "101")
```